# Use a controller variable in javascript (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to use my controller variable in my javascript.

Since this cannot be done straightforward. I use gon gem. https://github.com/gazay/gon

With this what I do is in a before filter of my base controller (Which acts as a before filter for all the controllers) I do gon.variable_name = value And in my js file I use gon.variable_name. This works fine for full page reloads.

But the variable is not getting updated for ajax request.

Say for example:

On page reload, in my controller I do

```
gon.variable_name = value1
```

and in my js, `gon.variable_name` gives me `value1`.

After a ajax request in my controller I do

```
gon.variable_name = value2
```

and in my js, I still see `gon.variable_name` as `value1` only.

Is there any way I could update gon.variable_name in a ajax request?

Thanks

Comment: Your ajax request presumably returns some json? That's where your value2 should go. Then, in success handler of that request you extract value2 from the response and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to initialize gon for every request inorder to update the variables.

> include_gon(:init => true)

in the response of every request solved the problem.

Extra tip:
For those who use ajaxify rails gem you can call this helper method in the ajaxify_extra_content method and in the content_inserted callback you can append this to the head tag to get it work in a generic way.

Thanks all for your suggestions and help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`watch: true`](https://github.com/gazay/gon/wiki/Usage-gon-watch) switch for `gon`:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<head>
  <%= include_gon(watch: true) %>

#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def update_vars
      @value1 = User.count
      gon.watch.value1 = @users_count
   end
end
```

This is what the documentation says. I don't agree with it, but should work.
It looks like `ajax polling` which is notoriously inefficient.

--

To give you some context, you have to remember that `gon` basically creates a small hash of javascript in your `layout`, populating it with the `gon` variables you've assigned in your controller:

```
<script>
   gon = {
      value1: "test",
      value2: "test"
   }
</script>
```

We've used it before here:

[image]

The reason this is important is because this `gon` JS variable is invoked at runtime -- meaning that it remains static until you reload the page.

The way around this is to either dynamically reload the `gon` variable values (using `watch` above) *or* pass the new value through your ajax request (like `Sergio` recommended in the comments):

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def update
      respond_to do |format|
         format.json { render json: {value_2: "test"}.to_json %> 
      end 
   end
end
```

You'd then be able to use it as follows:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/update",
   success: function(data) {
      var value2 = data.value2;
   }
});
```

Comment: Rich Peck and Sergio, Thanks.

Here, for all the ajax request in my app I want something to be updated in the view through js and for that I need values from db.

So to make it generic I have a method which gets called after every request and inside it I need the value to be accessible.

Since it is in a common asset file(to have it generic)I dont have access to the controller variable.For this reason I thought of using gon so that in a before filter I set the gon variables value and in the js I use it.

Unfortunately gon.watch also doesnt work for me.when I try to print, it says undefined

Comment: Hi Rich Peck, 

What am trying to do is to store some values from db in a gon variable and update them with every ajax request. And I perform some operations in my javascript file using those values.

But the gon variables are not getting updated with ajax request. (Only on page reload it gets updated.)

Comment: Not exactly but this answer gave me hint to solve my issue. Thanks Rich Peck.